# What is the age limit for racewalking (20k and 50k) for the Olympics?

Tags: olympics, track-and-field, racewalking

I am a race walker, and am interested to take part in the Olympics. But, as I google for the age limit in Olympic race walking, I find nothing.

I can see many race walkers are 20+ y.o. and I really want to know what is the minimum and the maximum age for Olympic race walking.

Comment: Which country's team are you hoping to join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took me a long time to find.

According to the USA Track & Field [rule book](http://www.usatf.org/usatf/files/2c/2cf4ef89-b3f9-43fe-82d8-66b94f21c546.pdf) for 2013, there is no maximum age limit for the main "OPEN" and "MASTERS" classifications of race walking. There is however a maximum age limit for other classifications.

**Classifications**

- OPEN

  - Minimum age: 14 years old.
  - Maximum age: NONE
- Junior

  - Minimum age: 14 years old.
  - Maximum age: 20 years old.
- Youth

  - Minimum age: 14 years old.
  - Maximum age: 19 years old.
- Masters

  - Minimum age: 35 years old.
  - Maximum age: NONE

Please read below.

> Except as otherwise provided herein or in USATF's Operating
>   Regulations, the following championship classifications shall be open
>   to all member athletes of USATF who have complied with the
>   requirements of these Rules, the Bylaws, and the Operating
>   Regulations:
>
> (a)  Open: The Open classification shall have no maximum age limit. In
>   men's and women's long distance running, the Open classification shall
>   be limited to athletes    sixteen (16) years and older on the day of the
>   competition. In Open men's race walking and all other Open women's
>   competition, athletes shall be fourteen (14) years or older on     the
>   day of the competition.
>
> (b) Junior: The Junior classification shall be limited to athletes who
>   are fourteen (14) years or older on the day of competition and will
>   not   become twenty (20) years of age duringthe year of the competition.
>
> (c) Youth: The Youth classification shall be limited to athletes who
>   have not attained nineteen (19) years of age as of the final day of
>   the National Junior Olympic Track and Field meet of the year of
>   competition.
>
> (d) Masters: In Track and Field and Race Walking, the Masters
>   classification shall be limited to athletes who are at least
>   thirty-five (35) years old on the first day of the meet. In Long
>   Distance Running, the Masters classification shall be limited to
>   athletes who are at least forty (40) years old on the first day of the
>   meet.

Comment: I tried to +1, as your answer is really informative, but as I lack reputation, I can't do it. By the way, which category athelets can take part in olympics?

Comment: Depends on your age. But if you are older than 14 years old, you would try out for the OPEN classification. Also it seems that you have enough reputation. Try again?

Comment: Haha! Thanks, last night when I was sleeping, my reputation grew tremendously, and now I can upvote! Thanks.I am 20 years old and will try hard.